# Is Timer created with eloop_register_timeout in hostapd runs asynchronously

Tags: c, timer

I wonder whether Timer created with

```
int eloop_register_timeout  (unsigned int   secs,
                             unsigned int   usecs,
                             eloop_timeout_handler  handler,
                             void *     eloop_data,
                             void *     user_data 
                             )
```

in hostapd runs asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the timer is run in the event loop thread when it expires.

Comment: You don't. It's part of the hostapd codebase, so the only example you will find is by looking in that code.